# On my application I put my moms phone number

Tags: applications

I'm a sophomore in high school and I don't have a phone. I'm applying for a job and I put my moms phone number down on mobile phone because I don't have a phone. Is this ok?

Comment: You can get a Tracfone for about $30, then you will have your own number for the foreseeable future. I did this when I was sending out resumes.

Comment: You can get a Google Voice number for free (in the U.S.).  It even works with text messaging.  Get one, and don't make that mistake again.

Comment: sophomore in high school or sophomore in college?

Comment: I think it is cool you are in high school and you don't have a phone.  I hope you get the job and see not problem with using your mom's number.

Comment: Did you write down on the application that you used someone else's number, and did you tell them you might be getting job-related messages? Otherwise, there might be some confusion happening.

Comment: Usually you don't have to supply a mobile number, if you have a home phone (land line).

Comment: Logically speaking a manager would call and ask, "Hello, is Dustin there?" And the other person would go, "Yes, hold on while I get him." They wouldn't inquire about the ownership of said phone line or about who answers first.

Answer (score 8):

If it is your only contact number, then you don't really have a choice.

I'm not overly familiar with the term "sophomore", but I assume you mean you are a 15-year old in high school. It isn't really all that unusual for someone that age to not have their own phone. On the other hand, a lot of teens do.

If you can get your own number (and as has been pointed out, there are free and cheap services available), that would be better, but there is nothing wrong with having your parent's number listed on your application (except the possibility that your mother with pre-filter any callback to you). Just make sure your parent knows that you've used their number, so they're not surprised when they get a call.

Edit: what is it with the word sophomore, anyway? Apparently, you may be in college, too - I would think having your own contact number is expected at that point, otherwise how would your mum contact you?

Comment: Sophomore means 'in second year out of four'. Usually applied to college years but can be applied high school too.

Comment: Horus - I think Sophomore is a US thing. I had to google it.

Comment: "It isn't really all that unusual for someone that age to not have their own phone" - in the US, it's pretty unusual these days.

Comment: Years 1-4 in high school or university are called Freshman, Sophomore, Junior, and Senior, respectively.

Comment: @WorkerDrone - data's a little old, but I wouldn't call 1 in 5 "unusual" http://www.pewinternet.org/2012/03/19/cell-phone-ownership/

Comment: @HorusKol - this was 5 years ago. And it said "Older teens ages 14 to 17 are substantially more likely to have a cell phone than younger teens ages 12 and 13 – 87% of older teens have a cell phone". So  only 13% didn't have phones 5 years ago. That number has certain decreased. Not that it matters, but I still call that "unusual".

Answer (score 6):

I'd actually be pleasantly surprised if a young potential hire used his mums phone number, and it would probably work in your favour with me at any rate.

In general there is nothing wrong with it, people your age are forgiven a lot of things (and paid peanuts). So I wouldn't worry about it if I were you, just let your parent know that you used their number.

Comment: This. Make sure your mom knows that there could be some incoming calls regarding your job applications, and everything should be fine.